# Are there any problems with the strategy of growing plants in pots till you decide where you want to plant them?

Tags: containers, propagation

I am still working on a layout for our garden. So far we have bought smaller plants that we would like to have in our garden (some cover plants and some accent plants and some bushes) that we still keep in pots till we decide where to plant them.
I am in the process to build an area half garden half nursery where I will either plant or put the plants in pots and bury the pots over the winter.

Do you foresee any problems with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep seedlings for a long time just avoid noon and afternoon sun so they don't dry out too fast. Water as needed, but remember in the nursery they are watered daily.  Don't let the pots sit in water over half an hour.

Comment: Are you saying that keeping the seedlings in pots is ok but care must be taken because that might accelerate he drying of the potting soil?

Comment: Yes, you need to take care of them by sheltering them from the hot sun and watering them on a similar schedule as they were at the nursery.  The potting soil has a month or two of nutrients in them.  Find a place where they get some direct sun, and where you can take care of the plants on a daily basis.   Avoid storing the plants on an asphalt driveway with 10 hrs of direct sunlight under those conditions they will parish from stress.  I prefer up against a house's foundation east side where plants get morning sun, and if you are in a place like Texas, I would store pots on the north side.

Comment: I put them in my own pots and change or improve the soil. I also try to decompress the root ball since some times the roots are completely packed in a too small pot. I make sure they have enough room to grow for an year and at that point I think that if I put the pots in the ground they are like planted, don't loos much water through vaporization etc etc